# Drupal 7 -- Would like to use unique profile template per role

Tags: theming, users

I'm working on a Drupal project where we have two main roles (students/teachers) + an admin role. I would like to have entirely different profile pages for the different roles.

At the moment I think the most maintainable method for doing this is going to be to have several profile template files that are called when the specific role is being viewed; I'm just not sure how to preprocess the profile to hint at the correct template.

At the moment, I've built some page pre-processing code to check the role of the profile page we're looking at as follows:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

  // See if we can influence profile pages
  $content = $vars['page']['content'];
  $theme = $content['system_main']['#theme'];

  if($theme == 'user_profile') {
    $roles = $content['system_main']['#account']->roles;

    if(in_array('teacher', $roles)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'teacher__user-profile.tpl.php';
    }
    elseif(in_array('student', $roles)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'student__user-profile.tpl.php';
    }

  }

}
```

The conditional correctly identifies the profiles being for teachers or students but I can't seem to influence it by suggesting a profile template.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: You could use panels to customise these - it has its own condition chain - but it's extra overhead if you're not using it for anything else as well

Comment: Thanks. I managed a fix but I'll have a look at that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It was just a matter of understanding how $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] works.

It works by taking a suggestion in the form of a prefix and then behind the scenes it adds the rest of the parts to create a path to your theme template.

So if you add "**page__mytemplate**" to $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], that suggestion will translate to **page--mytemplate.tpl.php**.

The problem is that I was giving it the whole name and not just the prefix.

The following code updates fixes my original attempt to make Drupal recognize my two custom templates:

- page--teacher.tpl.php
- page--student.tpl.php

Code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

  // Some variables to identify profile pages
  $content = $vars['page']['content'];
  $theme = $content['system_main']['#theme'];

  if($theme == 'user_profile') {
    $roles = $content['system_main']['#account']->roles;
    if(in_array('teacher', $roles)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__teacher';
    }
    elseif(in_array('student', $roles)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__student';
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else too.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey).

From the project page (emphasis added):

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or **role** -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a look. I resolved it following my earlier attempt but I could have used Theme Key in other projects so I'll keep it in mind.